# Discord.js Create a channel when a user reacts to a message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Would someone be able to assist me please, How would I get the below code to create a channel with all the users that react with the same emoji?

I am trying to make it so all users that react with the same battle emoji they will be put into the same channel then I will create multiple embeds with information on them. But for some reason I am been dumb and I don't know how to do this.

Sorry if this is simple but I am new to coding so any help is appreciated and I hope you all have a great Christmas.

```js
Client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user, message) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.Client) return;
  if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

  if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
    let member = await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    console.log(user);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will know how to create a text channel.

```js
<guild object>.channels.create('Text', {
    type: 'text',
        permissionOverwrites: [{
            id: <guild object>.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        }]
});
```

Creating a channel from a reaction is easy. See the example below.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); //Define Discord
const client = new Discord.Client(); //Define client

client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user, message) => { //Add an event listener
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.id === client.user.id) return; //If the reaction was from the bot, return
  if (!reaction.message.guild) return; //If the reaction was not in a guild

  if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
    let guild = reaction.message.guild
    guild.channels.create('channelName', { //Creating the channel
        type: 'text', //Make sure the channel is type is text
        permissionOverwrites: [ //Set overwrites
            {
                id: guild.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            }]
        })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life saver. I have been trying to do this for a week lol